# deploy node.js in heroku, js files in /public fold not loaded

Tags: node.js, heroku

The whole system works well in my local machine. Recently I deployed it the Heroku, I have a module called 'kindeditor' in the public fold. After running the system in Heroku, I found the 'kindeditor' in public fold is not loaded, because I can detect this from the chrome's developer tools.

Comment: will heroku prevent me from putting js files in the public fold?

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved, there is a setting in heroku called 'config variables', you just set this then all are working:

serve_static_assets    True